# Update SageMaker Jupyterlab environment

Tags: amazon-sagemaker, jupyter-lab

How can I update my SageMaker notebook's jupyter environment to the latest alpha release and then restart the process?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hi and thank you for using SageMaker!

To restart Jupyter from within a SageMaker Notebook Instance, you can issue the following command: `sudo initctl restart jupyter-server --no-wait`.

Best,
Kevin

Comment: Is there a way to start jupyter server from a specific conda environment?